# data.table - gsub (search text and replace with value of another column)

Tags: r, data.table, apply, gsub

I am looking to search and replace text from another column. Is it possible to leverage function from apply family?

I am looking for a solution preferably with just data.table and basic R. (prefer not to use other stringr etc packages)

```
library("data.table")
x <- mtcars
setDT(x)
x[,x1 := lapply(gear, gsub("1",gear,qsec))]
```

Comment: Did you meant `Map`

Comment: I mean gsub to search pattern and if there is a pattern then replace it with the value of another column. e.g. replacing "1" in qsec with value from "gear"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `Map` with `gsub`

```
x[, x1 := unlist(Map(function(x, y) gsub("1", x,y), gear, qsec))]
```

-output

```
> x$x1
 [1] "46.46" "47.02" "48.64" "39.44" "37.02" "20.22" "35.84" "20"    "22.9"  "48.3"  "48.9"  "37.4"  "37.6"  "38"    "37.98" "37.82" "37.42"
[18] "49.47" "48.52" "49.9"  "20.03" "36.87" "37.3"  "35.43" "37.05" "48.9"  "56.7"  "56.9"  "54.5"  "55.5"  "54.6"  "48.6"
```

Or use `str_replace`

```
library(stringr)
 x[, x1 := str_replace_all(qsec, '1', as.character(gear))]
```

Comment: thanks. map function sounds great. Is that syntax correct? It tries to remove column x1 when I executed it.

Comment: @R007 sorry, a typo in bracket placement. updatd